# How do I validate a concatenation from SQL in a PHP login script?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I am working on a login script that has 2 fields (fullname & password). My SQL table has ID, firstname, lastname, password. The user would choose their name from a select, with the select being dynamically populated from the concatenation of their firstname and lastname (fullname), then input their password.

```
//my SQL table
ID  |   firstname  |  lastname  |  password
-------------------------------------------
01      John          Smith        ezaccess


//my SQL query
$query2 = "SELECT CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname) AS fullname FROM tbl_users";
$result1 = mysqli_query($DBcon, $query2);


//my HTML select
<select class="form-control" name="fullname" required>
        <option value="">Select name</option>
        <?php while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)):;?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row1["fullname"];?>"><?php echo $row1["fullname"];?></option>
        <?php endwhile;?>
</select>
```

So this is where I get lost, the validation of the newly created 'fullname' select. Am I just better creating a fullname SQL column, then validating it? I understand I've just created the fullname array from my query, but don't know how to carry it forward for validating my login in the last query.

```
if (isset($_POST['btn-login'])) {

$fullname = strip_tags($_POST['fullname']);
$password = strip_tags($_POST['password']);

$fullname = $DBcon->real_escape_string($fullname);
$password = $DBcon->real_escape_string($password);

$query = $DBcon->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE firstname AND lastname='$fullname'");
$row=$query->fetch_array();

$count = $query->num_rows;

if (password_verify($password, $row['password']) && $count==1) {
    $_SESSION['userSession'] = $row['user_id'];
    header("Location: home.php");
} else {
    $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>
                <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign'></span> &nbsp; Invalid name or Password !
            </div>";
}
$DBcon->close();
```

}

Comment: Why would you use concat in the top query and not the bottom query?  It should be the same process.

Comment: `$query = $DBcon->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE firstname AND lastname='$fullname'");` change to `$query = $DBcon->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname)='$fullname'");`

Comment: You should also stop using escape strings, escaping password doesn't have a purpose here, and you should be using a prepared statement with a parameter for fullname.

Comment: Seems a bit odd to give them half of the data they need to login, most systems expect you to type it all in.

Comment: Also `while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)):;` that trailing semicolon should be removed.

Comment: @NigelRen This is for an internal form on a sandbox'd tablet. Trying to make it quick and easy to login, but want to track who did what/when, security isn't a priority in this instance.

Comment: @Devon I tried to use concat on the bottom query but couldn't get it to work so thought I was missing something. Will try harder :-)

Comment: @RayVM, you also should stop stripping things without knowing what you're doing.  Your strip tags would reduce a password of `so<mething` to just `so` making an account be able to be easily brute forced.  (or worse yet, any password that starts with a < would result in an empty string)

Comment: @OlexanderPobuta  That worked great! Greatly appreciated. Not sure why I didn't get it working before.

Comment: @Devon I'll keep that in mind for future projects, but security is not a priority at the minute, I just create pretty picture concepts.

Comment: @RayVM that's really no excuse.  Why do things the wrong way when it wouldn't take any more time to do it the right way?  There's absolutely no reason to use strip_tags here.

Comment: @Devon as I said, I provide working concepts. Security, clean code and other issues are for the next guy, unless of course I'm trying to create something extraordinary and need their input early on. If I wanted to write fully functioning and secure code I'd be a developer.

Comment: @RayVM working concept?  That's a contradiction.  Just use HTML if you're doing a demo.  I don't get why you'd waste your time on PHP that someone else is going to have to completely rewrite because of a bunch of faulty code.

Comment: @Devon what about functioning concept? Does that sit better with you in your pretty little head? I just like adding a bit of faulty code in for fun, keeps little whining girls who do it for a living in a job.

Comment: @RayVM lol.  but you come to those whiny girls for help because you can't get your faulty code to run.

Comment: @Devon touché lol.

Answer (score 1):

Although I played around with the concatenation, for some reason I didn't get it working, but this did the trick for the last query:

```
$query = $DBcon->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname)='$fullname'");
```

Please note that security isn't a priority in this instance, so my code would not be the most secure.